# Connect to RDS instance with spring from my computer

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I'm new to the AWS and Spring world, so I might get some things conceptually wrong...
So I set up an RDS instance on AWS that is currently publicly accessible.  From http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_data_access_with_jdbc I found the necessary bean configuration, which is

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/jdbc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/jdbc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/jdbc/spring-cloud-aws-jdbc.xsd">

 <aws-context:context-credentials>
  ...
 </aws-context:context-credentials>

 <aws-context:context-region region="..."/>

<jdbc:data-source
         db-instance-identifier="myRdsDatabase"
         password="${rdsPassword}">
</jdbc:data-source>
</beans>
```

Also from the internet, I filled in the ... with

```
<aws-context:context-credentials>
        <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
        <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${accessKey:}" secret-key="${secretKey:}"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>
```

Question number 1:  Upon running, I get this error: "There is no EC2 meta data available, because the application is not running in the EC2 environment. Region detection is only possible if the application is running on a EC2 instance."  I would like to try to resolve that error with the config options

```
cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
cloud.aws.region.auto=false
```

which would go in a .properties file somewhere, but I would like to put everything in the same xml file.  How can I translate these lines into their xml equivalent?

I don't know where to put the keys and passwords except in this xml file, so I just did that; so question number 2 is where should that stuff actually go?

Question 3: I'm assuming that jdbcTemplate will work because the datasource for jdbc is configured.  Is that true?  Can I, just from this configuration setup, use the line `jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE t IF EXISTS");` and have that happen in my RDS?

Question 4: Am I missing anything obvious from my setup if my current goal is just to connect and be able to make sql queries?

Comment: All you are trying to do is connect to a datasource configured in AWS RDS. you can simply make use of spring.datasource.* properties to configure a datasource. If you start using access id and access secret credentials, it can be easily misused and leads to security threat.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I initially tried to just configure a datasource in that way, and got the same errors where it tries to get metadata that it's not allowed to get because it's not on an s3 server, so I started looking into what spring wants for AWS specifically.

Comment: it may be because of spring cloud aws in classpath. Try to remove that dependency and check. provide more code /configuration/ logs to comment further

Comment: So I removed the dependencies and now I'm getting a different error later on in the build path.  Description:

"Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE"  So I'm led to believe that I'm not giving enough information to datasource.  All I give it is driver name: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", URL, username, and password.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please share your pom.xml to comment further